# Click list column, show item on Google Map

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, geolocation, google-maps

So I have this map working in SharePoint Online that is pulling column data into the InfoWindow and users can navigate the map and click on locations - this is all fine! (using JSLink)

What I want to somehow implement is being able to have another column where you would click on a symbol or some text and it would go to that item on the map and show the info bubble. I have used a star in the below image as an illustration pointing to what I would like to achieve.

[image]

This is the code I am using for the Info Window:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location, icon: rows[idx].MarkerIcon, content: '<b>'+rows[idx].Title+'</b><br />'+rows[idx].Location+'<br /><i class="fas fa-copy"> </i><b>WiFi: </b>'+rows[idx].WiFi+'<br /><b>Printer: </b>'+rows[idx].Printer+'<br /><b>Toilet: </b>'+rows[idx].Toilet+' <a href="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contosoHub/Lists/Locations/DispForm.aspx?ID='+rows[idx].ID+'" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:this.href = unescapeProperly(escape(this.href)); (function (url) {var opt = {url: url, autoSize: true, dialogReturnValueCallback: function(res, retVal) { if (res === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) { /*do something useful*/ } }}; SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(opt);})(this.href); return false;">Details</a>', title: rows[idx++].Title});
```

Any help with this would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: A easy way to achieve this would be calculated columns using HTML. This is only possible in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016 on premise. I see your "SharePoint Online" tag - is it really SPO what you are using?

Comment: Yes, using SharePoint Online.

Comment: Due to reduced functionality regarding calculated columns in SharePoint Online I am sorry I got no solution for your question. Hope someone else has a idea.